# Error while building app in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

this is what my dependencies look like and console error

[image: this is what my dependencies look like and console error]

and this is the second error view

[image: and this is the second error view]

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Please do not post Gradle files or stack traces as screen shot as it makes them hard to read. This is all text, just copy and paste it into your question and format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

Try invalidating cache and restart.

- Click **File** Menu and then click **Invalidate Caches** [step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m71dh.png).
- Make sure to check all **checkboxes**.
- Click on **Invalidate and Restart** [step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7uhY.png).

Comment: Can I see screenshot of your main activity and Gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

- As I can see through the log messages, the error is due to some mistake in DI Implementation(in your case its daggerHilt).
- Try of checking dagger annotations such as : `AndroidEntryPoint`, `hiltViewModel`
- Try checking gradle files once :`plugins { id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.47' apply false   }`
- Moreover, you can check my commit of Implementing DI in my own personal project. Follow this [LINK](https://github.com/utkarsh006/Cryptocurrency-app/commit/03c99cbe0285414b937670b16a5d64526bcb706c#diff-7fa6aef292187a049f7a4d6060d8df3ba212d838789c78940bd363344b1c38cd)